# /etc/sudoer/ - Is it possible to enter into single user mode through putty?

Tags: linux, centos, putty

I accidentally chown the /etc/sudoer/ folder so that my sudo command no longer works. (I can only ssh into this Linux Centos vm on windows azure) I don't have the root password and I wonder how I may reset the root password, or just chown the /etc/ folder back to root. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you boot a livecd with SSH access?  Or somehow attach to the disk from another system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

single user mode has no network so you cannot do so through ssh. if you cannot get the vm console access, you need to contact azure support to help you, such as have them boot the vm into a livecd and set up ssh access with sudo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got quite disappointed by microsoft support, as they said the product is in preview phase and all request should be direct to an online forum (seriously?). And that is a forum with few visitors. ;(

Comment: sounds like the other answer to your question may help you more then. this is what the azure support seems to be saying (though not the exact same problem as yours but analogous). you do need to mount the disk to another azure vm with root access and modify the data, and then restart the vm. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork/thread/92a55a09-19c9-4731-b7a6-2b1a9ea909f7

Answer (score 5):

If you can mount the harddrive in another VM with root access you can change the permissions.